# Is there an R function for converting character data to integer?

Tags: r, dataframe, replace

```r
Fruit <- c('Apple', 'Banana', 'Mango', 'Apple', 'Peach')
Price <- c(1,2,3,1,3)
data <- data.frame(Fruit, Price)
```

How can I change `data$Fruit` to `c(1,2,3,1,4)`? I mean, use integer to represent the name. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: `Fruit <- factor(Fruit)`. See `?factor` for details. That will store an integer internally and display the text. To convert that to a pure number `as.integer(factor(Fruit)`.

Answer (score 3):

In R, you can represent data like this as a *factor*. A factor is a type of vector that is stored as integers, such as the `c(1,2,3,4)` in your example.

Unlike a plain integer vector, each integer in a factor has a *label* or *level* associated with it, such as the `c('Apple', 'Banana', 'Mango', 'Apple', 'Peach')` in your example.

If you have a character vector, you can convert it to a factor with `as.factor()`. You can recover the unique labels/levels from a factor with the `levels()` function. And you can underlying the underlying integer values from a factor with `as.integer()`.

In your specific example, you would write:

```r
fruit <- c('Apple', 'Banana', 'Mango', 'Apple', 'Peach')
price <- c(1,2,3,1,3)
data <- data.frame(fruit, price)

data$fruit <- as.factor(data$fruit)
```

At this point, `data$fruit` is now a factor. You can get the integer values with `as.integer(data$fruit)`.

```r
fruit <- c('Apple', 'Banana', 'Mango', 'Apple', 'Peach')
price <- c(1,2,3,1,3)
data <- data.frame(fruit, price)

data$fruit <- as.factor(data$fruit)
data$fruit_num <- as.integer(data$fruit)

print(data$fruit_num)
# [1] 1 2 3 1 4
```

Note that you can also use `unclass` to obtain the integer codes from a factor, rather than `as.integer`. However this is somewhat reliant on implementation details in R, and it's clearer in most cases to use `as.integer`.

Note also that `data.frame` is an interesting case. Prior to R 4.0, `data.frame` *automatically* applied `as.factor` to any `character` columns in the input, unless you specified the `data.frame(..., stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`. After R 4.0, `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` is the default. However, if you *want* R

Relevant help topics:

- `?factor` and `?as.factor`
- `?levels` and `?nlevels`
- `?relevel` and `?reorder`
- The `stringsAsFactors` parameter in (not exhaustive):

  - `?options`
  - `?data.frame` and `as.data.frame`
  - `?read.table`, `?read.csv`, and `?read.csv2`

Comment: Thank you for all your work. It has took me two days. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

We can use `match`

```
 with(data, match(Fruit, unique(Fruit)))
[1] 1 2 3 1 4
```