# Error in R: Error in plot.window(...) : invalid 'ylim' value

Tags: r, plot, logistic-regression

I have a loan default data file from kaggle (loan.csv). I want to forecast the default rate using logistics regression.
I optimized the number of predictors from 145 to 28. I also eliminated all NaNs after the optimization.

The datafile looks like this:

```
$ loan_status                : chr  "Current" "Current" "Current" "Current" ...
$ grade                      : chr  "C" "D" "D" "D" ...
$ sub_grade                  : chr  "C1" "D2" "D1" "D2" ...
$ annual_inc                 : num  55000 90000 59280 92000 57250 ...
$ application_type           : chr  "Individual" "Individual" "Individual" "Individual" ...
$ avg_cur_bal                : int  1878 24763 18383 30505 9667 40338 5085 5235 9197 38025 ...
$ bc_util                    : num  5.9 8.3 0 75.2 8.9 64 90.8 35.9 60.6 94.4 ...
$ chargeoff_within_12_mths   : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ collections_12_mths_ex_med : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ delinq_2yrs                : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 ...
$ dti                        : num  18.2 26.5 10.5 16.7 26.4 ...
$ int_rate                   : num  13.6 18.9 18 18.9 16.1 ...
$ emp_length                 : chr  "10+ years" "10+ years" "6 years" "10+ years" ...
$ home_ownership             : chr  "RENT" "MORTGAGE" "MORTGAGE" "MORTGAGE" ...
$ mort_acc                   : int  0 3 2 3 2 6 1 3 1 3 ...
$ mths_since_last_major_derog: num  99 99 99 99 99 99 99 45 99 22 ...
$ mths_since_last_delinq     : num  99 71 99 99 99 99 99 32 17 22 ...
$ num_tl_120dpd_2m           : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ num_tl_30dpd               : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ num_tl_90g_dpd_24m         : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 ...
$ num_tl_op_past_12m         : int  3 6 0 3 5 4 0 6 2 2 ...
$ open_acc                   : int  9 13 8 10 12 18 19 8 38 6 ...
$ percent_bc_gt_75           : num  0 0 0 100 0 60 85.7 60 26.3 100 ...
$ pub_rec_bankruptcies       : int  1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ pub_rec                    : int  1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ revol_bal                  : int  4341 12315 4599 5468 829 53854 38476 8018 65950 4529 ...
$ tax_liens                  : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ total_acc                  : int  34 44 13 13 26 44 37 38 58 13 ...
```

loan_status is my response variable.
I tried to run some basic operations before converting some variables to factors:

```
par(mfrow = c(2,2))
qqnorm(dfbm3$loan_status, pch = 1, frame = FALSE, main = 'QQ-plot - Loan Status')
qqline(dfbm3$loan_status, col = "blue", lwd = 2)
boxplot(dfbm3$loan_status, main = 'Original data - Outliers')

grubbs.test(dfbm3$loan_status, type =10)
```

I got the error "Error in plot.window(...) : invalid 'ylim' value".

I tried to rerun it after converting "loan_status" into a binary variable (0 and 1), but the error persists. Initially, "loan_status" has nine (9) different char values.
So this is similar to a ranking ordinal regression.

Please, help!
Thank you

Comment: Perhaps I'm confused, but what does a Q-Q plot look like with strings? Normally it's a numeric process. I'm referring to `qqnorm(dfbm3$loan_status, ...)`, and your "sample data" of `$ loan_status : chr  "Current" ...`. Speaking of that, we can't really use the `str` representation of data, please provide sample data with `dput` instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

qq plots are used to check variable numeric data against some sort of model data, whether that be a normal curve or something else. You need numeric data, and even if you convert to 1's and 0's, they might still be `chr` values.

This could help there (but I don't think that is your underlying problem, see below).

[Is there an R function for converting character data to integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68349769/is-there-an-r-function-for-converting-character-data-to-integer)

In this case, I think you have the cart before the horse, and you should be running your qq plot on your `glm()` to test that your residuals are normal (or gamma or whatever you are testing against) and therefore satisfy the assumptions.

Also note that Logistic Regression on 9 factors is going to be quite, errr, how do I say this,  loosy goosy, i.e. your R-squareds are going to be interesting. If ranking is valid in this situation (I have my doubts), but that would be better. This part of the issue is probably better sorted on StackExchange, rather than StackOverflow.

Comment: Good point about factors. I do not intend to use them all. I want to try a stepwise backward regression to choose significant factors. So far, there are more numerical predictors than char ones. Trial and errors.

Comment: By "9 factors", I technically meant the 9 levels in ""loan_status" has nine (9) different char values", but that might not be an issue if you were validly able to get them down to 0 and 1.